# Filtering (dplyr) factor levels does not filter all rows that it should

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset of political parties. I want to plot the elecotral results of some of these as a line_geom. I only want some parties to be displayed. So I am filtering the factor levels of the parties I want. As can be seen by table() below, for the party PSOE, for instance, I have values for every election year, but these are not filtered out correctly (e.g. 1993, 1996, 2004), nor plotted afterward. I cannot understand why this is happening.

I though it may have to do with the fact that some parties did not participate in elections in all the years, so I am only plotting for PSOE and PP. But I would in fact like to filter and have displayed also those parties on the respective filter line after the hashtag.

Please help:

```
trial <- structure(list(year = c(1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 
                                 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
                                 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
                                 1979L, 1979L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
                                 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 
                                 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
                                 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
                                 1989L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 
                                 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
                                 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
                                 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2004L, 
                                 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
                                 2004L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
                                 2008L, 2008L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
                                 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
                                 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
                                 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
                                 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
                                 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
                                 2019L), partido = structure(c(30L, 28L, 23L, 2L, 29L, 10L, 24L, 
                                                               31L, 15L, 14L, 5L, 19L, 30L, 28L, 23L, 2L, 10L, 32L, 27L, 24L, 
                                                               17L, 15L, 14L, 4L, 22L, 33L, 28L, 2L, 30L, 23L, 10L, 7L, 24L, 
                                                               17L, 15L, 14L, 28L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 23L, 24L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 22L, 
                                                               6L, 35L, 28L, 2L, 23L, 7L, 10L, 24L, 17L, 21L, 35L, 13L, 14L, 
                                                               22L, 6L, 28L, 2L, 23L, 10L, 24L, 6L, 17L, 15L, 22L, 13L, 35L, 
                                                               2L, 28L, 23L, 10L, 24L, 6L, 3L, 17L, 15L, 13L, 35L, 2L, 28L, 
                                                               23L, 10L, 24L, 3L, 6L, 21L, 15L, 18L, 13L, 9L, 28L, 2L, 23L, 
                                                               10L, 15L, 24L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 20L, 28L, 2L, 23L, 10L, 24L, 
                                                               34L, 15L, 3L, 6L, 20L, 2L, 28L, 23L, 34L, 10L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 
                                                               3L, 6L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 2L, 28L, 11L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 25L, 15L, 
                                                               10L, 25L, 24L, 17L, 6L, 2L, 28L, 25L, 11L, 25L, 25L, 15L, 10L, 
                                                               25L, 24L, 17L, 6L, 28L, 2L, 11L, 25L, 36L, 15L, 25L, 10L, 24L, 
                                                               17L, 25L, 12L, 6L, 37L, 26L), .Label = c("AMAIUR", "AP/PP", "BNG", 
                                                                                                        "C-UPC", "CAIC", "CC", "CDS", "CG", "CHA", "CIU/PDECAT", "CIUDADANOS", 
                                                                                                        "COMPROMIS", "EA", "EE", "ERC", "FAC", "HB/EHBILDU", "IC-V", 
                                                                                                        "INDEP", "NABAI/GBAI", "PA", "PAR", "PCE/IU", "PNV", "PODEMOS", 
                                                                                                        "PRC", "PSA-PA", "PSOE", "PSP-US", "UCD", "UDC-IDCC", "UN", "UPN", 
                                                                                                        "UPYD", "UV", "VOX", "NA+"), class = "factor"), diputadosPerc = c(47.1428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          33.7142857142857, 5.71428571428571, 4.57142857142857, 1.71428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          3.14285714285714, 2.28571428571429, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 48, 
                                                                                                                                                                          34.5714285714286, 6.57142857142857, 2.57142857142857, 2.28571428571429, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 1.42857142857143, 2, 0.857142857142857, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          57.7142857142857, 30.5714285714286, 3.14285714285714, 1.14285714285714, 
                                                                                                                                                                          3.42857142857143, 0.571428571428571, 2.28571428571429, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 52.5714285714286, 30, 5.42857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                                                          5.14285714285714, 2, 1.71428571428571, 1.42857142857143, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          50, 30.5714285714286, 4.85714285714286, 4, 5.14285714285714, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1.42857142857143, 1.14285714285714, 0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          45.4285714285714, 40.2857142857143, 5.14285714285714, 4.85714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1.42857142857143, 1.14285714285714, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 44.5714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          40.2857142857143, 6, 4.57142857142857, 1.42857142857143, 1.14285714285714, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 52.2857142857143, 35.7142857142857, 2.28571428571429, 
                                                                                                                                                                          4.28571428571429, 2, 0.857142857142857, 1.14285714285714, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          46.8571428571429, 42.2857142857143, 1.42857142857143, 2.85714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2.28571428571429, 2, 0.857142857142857, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 48.2857142857143, 44, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2.85714285714286, 1.71428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 0.857142857142857, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 53.1428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          31.4285714285714, 3.14285714285714, 1.42857142857143, 4.57142857142857, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2, 1.42857142857143, 0.857142857142857, 0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 35.1428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          25.7142857142857, 11.4285714285714, 12, 3.42857142857143, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2.57142857142857, 2.57142857142857, 2.28571428571429, 1.71428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1.71428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 39.1428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          24.2857142857143, 12.8571428571429, 9.14285714285714, 3.42857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2.57142857142857, 2.57142857142857, 2.28571428571429, 1.42857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1.42857142857143, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 35.1428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          18.8571428571429, 16.2857142857143, 9.42857142857143, 6.85714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                          4.28571428571429, 2, 2, 1.71428571428571, 1.14285714285714, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 0.285714285714286
                                                                                                        ), diputadosAbs = c(165, 118, 20, 16, 6, 11, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                            168, 121, 23, 9, 8, 1, 5, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 202, 107, 11, 
                                                                                                                            4, 12, 2, 8, 2, 1, 1, 184, 105, 19, 18, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                            1, 175, 107, 17, 14, 18, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 159, 141, 18, 
                                                                                                                            17, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 156, 141, 21, 16, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                            1, 183, 125, 8, 15, 7, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 164, 148, 5, 10, 
                                                                                                                            8, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 169, 154, 2, 10, 6, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 186, 
                                                                                                                            110, 11, 5, 16, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 123, 90, 40, 42, 12, 
                                                                                                                            2, 9, 9, 8, 6, 6, 2, 1, 137, 85, 45, 32, 12, 9, 9, 8, 5, 5, 2, 
                                                                                                                            1, 123, 66, 57, 33, 24, 15, 7, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   -169L), class = "data.frame")
```

.

```
table(trial$partido, trial$year)
trial %>% 
  filter(partido == c("PSOE", "AP/PP")) %>% #, "CIU/PDECAT", "PNV","PCE/IU", "CDS", "UCD")) %>%
  select(year, partido, diputadosPerc) %>%
  # melt(natElecSeatsOnly, id = "year", measure.vars = names(natElecSeatsOnly)[c(2,14)], variable.name = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, diputadosPerc, colour=partido)) + geom_line()
```

.

```
Session info: R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.4.3  bindrcpp_0.2.2  forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.8     purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.3.1    
 [8] tidyr_0.8.2     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.0     compiler_3.5.2   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1     
 [7] tools_3.5.2      digest_0.6.18    jsonlite_1.5     lubridate_1.7.4  nlme_3.1-137     gtable_0.2.0    
[13] lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.0.1    cli_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.8   yaml_2.2.0      
[19] haven_2.1.0      withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       knitr_1.20       hms_0.4.2       
[25] grid_3.5.2       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.0       R6_2.3.0         readxl_1.1.0     modelr_0.1.2    
[31] magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.2  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2
[37] labeling_0.3     stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Error in filter(., partido == c("PSOE", "AP/PP")) : 
  object 'partido' not found

Comment: My code (i.e. the one posted here) does not return that error when I execute it. What I get is: Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(partido, c("PSOE", "AP/PP")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Run your code in a completely new session.

Comment: if you use a vector for filtering (any logical expression), use `x %in% y` instead. In your example `filter(partido %in% c("PSOE", "AP/PP")) `

Comment: Same problem as before, restarting R and re-executing did not work.

Comment: That did the trick, why don't u post it as an answer and I can tick it for u! And thank you! It is weird that it worked for some years though and not for others...!

Comment: @user5783745 posted the answer a few seconds after my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%`, like so

```
trial %>% 
  filter(partido %in% c("PSOE", "AP/PP")) %>% #, "CIU/PDECAT", "PNV","PCE/IU", "CDS", "UCD")) %>%
  select(year, partido, diputadosPerc) %>%
  # melt(natElecSeatsOnly, id = "year", measure.vars = names(natElecSeatsOnly)[c(2,14)], variable.name = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, diputadosPerc, colour=partido)) + geom_line()
```